# Must restart Visual Studio for source generator files to be picked up

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sourcegenerators

I have a source generator class library that works but the consumer project picks up the latest generated code only after restarting Visual Studio.

That is quite inconvenient to say the least, to restart Visual Studio instead of just rebuilding the solution.

Tried to unload/reload projects/solution, nothing.

Tried to clear the cache in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ComponentModelCache`, nothing.

Using the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 as of today.

The actual source generator, the simplest possible one:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [Generator]
    public class Class1 : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
        }

        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            context.AddSource("test.g.cs", $"// {DateTime.Now:F}");
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See point 8 [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) : unfortunately that is still required

Comment: Yes, it's been a couple of years now and situation hasn't improved...

Comment: You can unload/load generators project instead of restarting the VS

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

To save yourself from restarting Visual Studio you can run `dotnet build-server shutdown`. This clears the cache.

I've added this to the pre-build step of my source generator project which seems to do the trick.

I found this solution in a [Microsoft Learn Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1184090/looking-for-assistance-clearing-the-cache-for-upda). Credit goes to Suchiman who originally gave this answer:

"the way it works is, that csc.exe, the C# compiler, usually spins up a "compilation server" by the name of VBCSCompiler.exe (to avoid the JIToverhead of starting the process over and over again). csc.exe in that case just takes the parameters and forwards them via IPC to VBCSCompiler.exe to do the work. That compiler process will shut down if VS shuts down and if it's being used outside of VS, it has an idle timeout. A source generator is a compiler plugin so VBCSCompiler would load that source generator dll and execute it but it will not pick up changes to the dll once it has been loaded"

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not reliable.